# Where are stored the files uploaded to DHIS2? in which location on the server are the uploaded files stored?

Tags: dhis2

We are trying to create an automatic backup of the files uploaded to DHIS2 and wondering where are the files uploaded stored?

Answer (score 1):

Browsing through the documentation shows that the files by default should be located in the `/files` directory of the `DHIS2_HOME` environment variable.

> DHIS 2 is capable of capturing and storing files. By default files will be stored on the file system of the server which runs DHIS 2 in a files directory under the DHIS2_HOME external directory location.
>
> DHIS2 will look for an environment variable called DHIS2_HOME to locate the DHIS2 configuration directory. This directory will be referred to as DHIS2_HOME